# Computing $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{\exp x} \ dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

I know that $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{\exp x} = -\gamma $$ where $ \gamma $ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but I have no idea how to prove this.

The series definition of $ \gamma $ leads me to believe that I should break the integrand into a series and interchange the summation and integration, but I can't think of a good series. The Maclaurin series of $ \ln x $ isn't applicable as the domain of $ x $ is not correct and I can't seem to manipulate the integrand so that such a Maclaurin series will work.

Another thing I thought of was using $ x \mapsto \log u $ to get $ \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log \log u}{u^2} \ du $ and use some sort of contour integration, but I can't see how that would work out either.

Comment: If you don't know how to prove it, you can believe it, but you can't know it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

lemma1:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{x}dx-\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}dx=\gamma$$

pf:use 
\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{i}&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-t^n}{1-t}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{n}\dfrac{1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^n}{x}dx
\end{align}
and
$$\ln{n}=\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$$
so
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{i}-\ln{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-(1-x/n)^n}{x}dx-\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{(1-x/n)^n}{x}dx\right)$$

so
$$\gamma=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{x}dx-\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{1}(1-e^{-x})d(\ln{x})-\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x}d(\ln{x})=\cdots=-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln{x}dx$$

Comment: For those who are wondering, I chose this one as it has the most elementary solution, relying only on the definition of $ \gamma $ as opposed to falling back on special functions.

Comment: How has $\int_{1}^{n}\frac{(1-x/n)^n}{x}dx$ appeared? And how was its limit for $n\to\infty$ evaluated?

Comment: The last step is unclear to me. Can someone explain what happens in the dotdotdots?

Comment: The dots represent integration by parts (boundary terms disappear)

Comment: The passage to the limit is easily justified by dominated convergence, since for $0\le x\le n$ we have $0\le 1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^n\le x$ (by Bernoulli's inequality) and $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n\le e^{-x}$ (thanks to $1-t\le e^{-t}$)

Comment: @user They replaced $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}-\ln n$ with: $$\int_0^n\frac{1-(1-x/n)^n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_1^n\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{1-(1-x/n)^n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^n\left(\frac{1-(1-x/n)^n}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$And latterly used $(1-x/n)^n\to e^{-x}$ pointwise + a dominated convergence argument (actually, you don't need DCT but it's the simplest way, iirc)

Answer (score 13):

Here is one way, just derived it (by the way, the integral is equal to $-\gamma$). We know from Euler that you can write the logarithm as the following limit

$$\mathrm{ln}(x)=\lim_{n \to 0}\frac{x^n-1}{n}$$

The integral is now

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{ln} x}{\exp x}dx=\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^n-1}{e^x}dx$$

This is just the Euler integral of second kind, thus you get

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{ln} x}{\exp x}dx=\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{\Gamma(n
+1)-1}{n}=-\gamma$$

Comment: +1.  By the way, if you put your $\TeX$ in double dollar signs ($\$\$$ .... stuff .... $\$\$$), then the $\TeX$ gets centered and renders a bit better.

Answer (score 12):

Recalling the [Mellin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) of a function $f$

> $$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)dx \implies  F'(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}\ln(x)f(x) dx.$$

So, taking $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and finding its Mellin transform

> $$ F(s)=\Gamma(s) \implies F'(s)=\Gamma'(s)  $$

Taking the limit as $s\to 1$ yields the desired resuly

> $$ \lim_{s\to 1}F'(s)=-\gamma. $$

**Note:** You can use the identity to find the limit

> $$ \psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}\implies \Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x), $$

where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and $\psi(1)=-\gamma$.

Answer (score 11):

For $x\le n$, $\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ increases with $n$. By [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n}
&=\left(\frac{(n+1-x)\,n}{(n+1)(n-x)}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)\\
&=\left(1+\frac{x}{(n+1)(n-x)}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)\\[6pt]
&\ge\left(1+\frac{x}{n-x}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)\\[9pt]
&=\frac{n}{n-x}\frac{n-x}{n}\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, by [Monotone Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem),
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\log(x)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\log(x)\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1(\log(x)+\log(n))\,(1-x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1(\log(1-x)+\log(n))\,x^n\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\log(n)-n\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}x^n\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\log(n)-n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(n+k+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\log(n)-\frac{n}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{n+k+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k\right)\\[6pt]
&=-\gamma
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 6):

This is just the definition of the gamma function:
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx.$$
Differentiating it with respect to $s$ and then setting $s=1$, we get
$$-\gamma=\psi(1)=\left[\frac{d}{ds}\ln\Gamma(s)\right]_{s=1}=\int_0^{\infty}\ln x\,e^{-x}dx.$$

Comment: It's not completely clear to me how you get the log under the integral.

Comment: @NickKidman $$\frac{d\Gamma(s)}{ds}=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^{\infty }x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}\ln x\,e^{-x}dx.$$
Then it suffices to set $s=1$ in the final expression.

Comment: Ah okay, because the denominator in $\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s)$ becomes $1!$.

Comment: @NickKidman Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

We are all familiar with the [famous limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/904484/3) $~\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}h~=~\ln a,~$ which, by the simple

substitution $h~=~\dfrac1n,~$ becomes $~\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}~n\Big(\sqrt[^n]a-1\Big)~=~\ln a.~$ At the same time, using the

Taylor [series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) of $~\ln(1-t)~=-\displaystyle\sum_{k~=~1}^\infty\frac{t^k}k,~$ we can show, by switching the order

of summation and integration, and appealing to [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), that $$\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-\sqrt[^n]x\Big)~dx~=-H_n,$$ the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). By combining the two formulas, we have $$\begin{align}\gamma&~=~\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[H_n-\ln n\bigg]~=~\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[-\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-\sqrt[^n]x\Big)~dx-\int_0^1\ln n~dx\bigg]~=~\\\\&~=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\ln\bigg[n\Big(1-\sqrt[^n]x\Big)\bigg]~dx~=-\int_0^1\ln\big(-\ln x\big)~dx~=-\Gamma'(1),
\end{align}$$ where the last identity has been obtained by [differentiating under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) Euler's

first historical expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History), $~n!~=~\displaystyle\int_0^1\big(-\ln x\big)^n~dx,~$ at $n~=~0$. But the

same function can also be written as $~n!~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x}~dx,~$ which, when [differentiated under 

 the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) at $n~=~0$, yields the original integral. QED.