# Derivative of the Gamma function

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

How do you prove that
$$
\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma,
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Comment: What definition the the gamma function are you using?

Comment: And what definition of $\gamma$?

Comment: Would [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/902574/2) answer your question ?

Answer (score 27):

Consider the integral form of the Gamma function,
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{x-1} \, dt
\end{align}
taking the derivative with respect to $x$ yields
\begin{align}
\Gamma'(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{x-1} \, \ln(t) \, dt.
\end{align}
Setting $x=1$ leads to
\begin{align}
\Gamma'(1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \ln(t) \, dt.
\end{align}
This is one of the many definitions of the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Hence,
\begin{align}
\Gamma'(1) = - \gamma = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \ln(t) \, dt.
\end{align}

Comment: How to take derivative with respect to x of$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{x-1} \, dt$?

Comment: @Jonathen Look up "differentiation under the integral sign".

Answer (score 17):

The Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function gives:
$$\Gamma(z+1)=e^{-\gamma z}\cdot\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{z/n}\tag{1}$$
hence by considering $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ of both terms we get:
$$ \psi(z+1)=\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}=-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right) \tag{2}$$
and by evaluating the previous identity in $z=0$ it follows that:
$$ \psi(1) = \Gamma'(1) = -\gamma.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong I cannot delete my post because I having trouble singing in sorry for my lapse in judgement and failed math skills I will try to be better the solutions above work just fine.
$$\Gamma^{\prime}(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt =  \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{d}{dz} e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt = 
\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-t} \frac{d}{dz} t^{z-1} dt =
\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-t} ln(t) t^{z-1} dt$$
$$\Gamma^{\prime}(1) = \int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-t} ln(t) t^{1-1} dt = \int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-t} ln(t)  dt$$ this integral can be solved numerically to show that it comes out to $$-\gamma_{\,_\mathrm{EM}}$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1853811)