# Prove $(n-1)! + 1 = n^2$ has only one integer solution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, gamma-function, digamma-function

Prove $(n-1)! + 1 = n^2$ has only one integer solution, namely $5$.

I think that we can use [the derivate of the gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246766/derivative-of-the-gamma-function) to say that the LHS is growing more than the RHS from $n=5$ onwards, so it can not have solutions bigger than $5$. But computing the value of $\Gamma'(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{x-1} \, \ln(t) \, dt$ and proving this is strictly bigger than $2n$ is where I get stuck.

Comment: Hint: write it as $\,(n-1)!=(n-1)(n+1)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, its my mistake, I  didn't saw that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$(n-1)! +1 \geq (n-1)(n-2)(n-3) +1$$ for all $n > 3,$ and then compare $(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) +1$ with $n^{2}.$ Since both are polynomials, this should not be too difficult.