# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\left [ \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{x} +\frac{2}{\ln\left ( 1-x \right )}\right ]\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\left [ \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{x} +\frac{2}{\ln\left ( 1-x \right )}\right ]\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried to let $1-x\rightarrow x$ ,and got
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left [ \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{x} +\frac{2}{\ln\left ( 1-x \right )}\right ]\, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1-x}+\frac{2}{\ln x}\right )\, \mathrm{d}x$$
but I have been stuck here for a long time, any idea on how to go futher?

Edit:with the help of Mathematica,I got an answer below

[image]

Comment: if have closed form  first step you can $\sqrt{x}=t$

Comment: Integral $\int_0^1\frac{2}{\ln x}dx$ is unbounded

Comment: For first fraction let $x=\sin^4 t$ and obtain $4\ln|\cos t|+\cos2t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\gamma = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \stackrel{F}{=} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(e^{-nx}-\frac{e^{-nx}-e^{-(n+1)x}}{x}\right)\,dx \tag{1}$$
where $F$ stands for [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). That leads to:
$$ \gamma = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x e^x}\right)\,dx  = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\,du \tag{2}$$
so the given integral equals:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{u}}{1-u}+\frac{2}{\log u}\right)\,du = 2\gamma+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-1+\sqrt{u}}{1-u}\,du\tag{3}$$
or:
$$ 2\gamma - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{1+\sqrt{u}} = 2\gamma -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2v\,dv}{1+v} = \color{red}{2(\gamma+\log 2-1)}\tag{4}$$
as wanted.

Comment: This is nice, but it begs the question: how did you know $\;\gamma\;$ was involved in this mess **before** solving the integral? I first made two substitutions and simplifcations until I did $\;e^{-u}:=1-x\;$ and got something close to an integral expression of $\;\gamma\;$, and even heavily suspected that something like $\;2\gamma\;$ is there, and then your answer came in so I stopped.

Comment: @DonAntonio: the presence of $\gamma$ is suggested by the presence of the term $\frac{1}{\log(1-x)}$ in the integrand function, whose singularity in the origin is compensated by the presence of the other term. The RHS of $(2)$ is pretty well-known.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. I know about (1) and (2), yet it would be smoother, or perhaps more "educative", to begin with the integral expression and then compare with the known integral expression for $\;\gamma\;$, otherwise it looks, imo, as hokus pokus. Very nice answer, though. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider $$I\left(\epsilon\right)=\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{x}dx+2\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{\log\left(1-x\right)}dx
 $$ we get $$\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{x}dx=-\log\left(\epsilon\right)+2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-\epsilon}}\frac{u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}du
 $$ $$=-\log\left(\epsilon\right)-2\sqrt{1-\epsilon}-\log\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\epsilon}}{1+\sqrt{1-\epsilon}}\right)
 $$ and $$2\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{\log\left(1-x\right)}dx=2\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)dx+2\log\left(\epsilon\right)-2\log\left(1-\epsilon\right)
 $$ then $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{x}+\frac{2}{\log\left(1-x\right)}\right)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\left(-2\sqrt{1-\epsilon}-\log\left(\frac{\left(1-\epsilon\right)\left(1-\sqrt{1-\epsilon}\right)}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\epsilon}\right)\epsilon}\right)+2\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)dx\right)\tag{1}
 $$ $$=\color{blue}{-2+\log\left(4\right)+2\gamma}.$$ The calculation of the integral in the RHS of $(1)$ is classical and can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980593/some-integral-representations-of-the-euler-mascheroni-constant).

Comment: Nice approach! Got it,thx!

Answer (score 1):

> *I have been stuck here for a long time, any idea on how to go further?*

Yes. For starters, rewrite $~\dfrac{1+\sqrt x}{1-x}~$ as $~\dfrac1{1-\sqrt x}~,~$ then let $x=t^2,~$ and rewrite $~\dfrac t{1-t}~$ as

$1-\dfrac1{1-t}.~$ You'll be eventually left with $\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(\frac1{1-x}~+~\frac x{\ln x}\right)~dx,~$ which is much better

looking. Taking each part individually, and inserting certain helpful parameters, we [have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{x^\epsilon}{(1-x)^{1-\epsilon}}~dx~=~B(\epsilon,~1+\epsilon),~$ [and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $~\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{x}{\ln^{1-\epsilon}x}~dx~=~-\left(-\frac12\right)^\epsilon~\Gamma(\epsilon),~$ ultimately

leaving us with evaluating $~\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}~B(\epsilon,~1+\epsilon)~-~\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon)}{2^\epsilon}~=~\gamma~+~\ln2.$

Comment: It's very nice! thx!

Comment: You said you are stuck ? where ?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{{1 + \root{1 - x} \over x} + {2 \over \ln\pars{1 - x}}}
\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{\root{1 - x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
2\int_{0}^{1}{x \over 1 - x}\
\overbrace{\bracks{1 + {1 - x \over \ln\pars{x}}}}
^{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{t}}\,\dd t}}\ \,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x - x^{t + 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\dd t =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t + 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x - \int_{0}^{1}\dd x}\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{1}\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}\bracks{\vphantom{\large A} \Psi\pars{t + 2} + \gamma} - 1}\,\dd t\qquad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\bracks{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{3} \over \Gamma\pars{2}} + \gamma - 1}\qquad
\pars{~\Gamma:\ Gamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{\ds{2\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\gamma + \ln\pars{2} - 1}}}
\end{align}

> In \eqref{1}, I used the well known identity $\ds{\mathbf{6.3.22}}$ from
>   [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).