# A collection of definite integrals with their derivations

Tags: definite-integrals, book-recommendation

Is there any book which includes proofs of the following integrals (and perhaps many other important definite integrals)?

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any books, some of these integrals have been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980593/some-integral-representations-of-the-euler-mascheroni-constant) though.

Comment: @Hamed, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195434/justify-the-steps-of-the-integral-representations-of-the-euler-mascheroni-consta) is another one.